# App runs on simulator but can't build on iso device: Linker error build Failed duplicate symbol GoogleMaps.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-api-3

[image: Google maps framework. Linker error. Duplicate symbol.]

This problem occurred after installing pod for google maps api

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of research finally found out that there was no problem with **GoogleMaps.framework** neither with my project. All what required was **Update Xcode**. In **version 6.2 the problem was there** with no solution but **after updating to 6.3.1 all problems are gone**! Could be an xCode bug. Now I can breathe!!!